# Design for a long and short distance radio wave communicating lifeform

Tags: creature-design, physics, xenobiology

Having read previous questions on radio wave communication on biological creatures would it make sense for race of alien creatures to have developed dish like bone structures for radio wave communication( metal if needed and assuming they had all organelles needed)

soldier types of the species would have smaller dishes at the back of their head facing forward (purely for aesthetic reasons with antler type horns at the side to protect the dish and act as defence) able to have information relayed from other soldiers, giving it a 3 dimensional view from information given from watching soldiers as well as orders and update.

Larger creatures almost triceratops like, their horn acting as the feed horn and frequency receiver and their back shield structure as the satellite dish large enough to receive long distance radio waves from within the solar system or for observetory reasons or as a really slow (years of waiting) for interstellar messenges if they play a stealth role in enemy planets.

would these dish like structures make evolutionary sense or would small transmitters and receivers within the creatures body hidden from view be more effective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think about why a critter would need to communicate over a given distance.

If a critter is more-or-less planet based, it's hard to see how it gets interstellar travel through evolution. And if it does not *go* there, it's hard to think why it wants to talk to anybody there. Especially on an evolutionary basis.

Radio signals are not particularly easy to produce or detect. Especially in the naive methods you might consider starting with, such as spark gaps. So those first few evolutionary steps are very difficult, and have not much payout. The distance one could imaging a primitive radio being detected over could much more easily be spanned with sound or visible signals. Or even smells!

A space-based life form would have many other demands and incentives. And it has very different constraints and capabilities on size, mass, and structural strength.

It might well be many 100's of thousands of km away from it's buddies. Sound won't work. It might well be out of easy visual range. Imagine the various space-borne critters we have seen in Star Trek, for example. Baby space-whale is bouncing around in the asteroids and stubs it's, well, whatever it calls its extremities. And it wants mom *NOW*. So it needs to call out somehow. Maybe at first it just has a "zzzt" kind of spark thing that mom can detect. Later generations get more sophisticated, adding first simple di-pole antennas and maybe later a dish or some such. Possibly different antennae for different purposes. Adding sensitivity, direction accuracy, etc.

Possibly it develops a whole range of electromagnetic emitting devices hitting a variety of wavelengths for special purposes. Maybe it can do something like a radar scan to detect asteroids and such. Maybe it can even start to do something like spectro-photography to detect chemicals in asteroids. Maybe it can use it's sensory devices to know when the sun is going to flare and it needs to stand behind an asteroid for a while.

Maybe electromagnetic displays become part of mating. So young Miss Space-Whale is very selective about the performances that young Bachelor Space-Whale puts on to entice her. And generation after generation of the best radio-display being the one that gets all the girls, after a while they become hugely adept.

Comment: good answer, some very interesting suggestions thank you

Answer (score 1):

> giving it a 3 dimensional view from information given from watching soldiers as well as orders and update.

A problem you'll run into is [bandwidth limitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_(signal_processing)). There are probably too many tradeoffs to list here, but you will have to trade off range, resistance to interference and rate of communication. A 3D view sounds like quite a complex thing, and if you want it updated you'll need to share quite a lot of information. The human optic nerve apparently manages a few megabits and that's quite high.

High bandwidths mean high frequencies, and that means line of sight only unless you do some sort of complex relaying, and the difficulties of generating VHF (or higher) with wetware will be considerable.

Low bandwidth, low signal rate stuff sounds much less implausible. Think morse code, not video calls. It *can* be possible to send images over bandwidth-constrained links, using stuff like [slow-scan television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-scan_television), but this would be far from simple to make, let alone evolve.

> receive long distance radio waves from within the solar system

Here's a picture of part of the [Deep Space Network](https://www.nasa.gov/directorates/heo/scan/services/networks/dsn), used for in-system communication. Those dishes are pretty big, as you can see.

[image: Deep Space Network]

> or for observetory reasons or as a really slow (years of waiting) for interstellar messenges

And here's a picture of [Arecibo radio observatory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecibo_Observatory). Also quite large.

[image: Arecibo]

You either need massive antennae, very high power transmissions and ideally both. The calorific burden for a land animal sounds punishing!

> would these dish like structures make evolutionary sense or would small transmitters and receivers within the creatures body hidden from view be more effective?

The radio itself makes limited evolutionary sense, especially in its very long distance or very high bandwidth forms.

That aside, you don't want your radio antennae to be too close to big wet conductive things, like most animal bodies. Horns would make for much better aerials than patches on (or worse, under) the skin.

Comment: good answer thanks